# How to populate an array using OpenMP-MPI hybrid paradigm in C?

Tags: c, mpi, openmp

I'm using this really simple code to populate an array using both MPI and OpenMP:

```
int main( int argc , char * argv[] ){
   
   double test[6];
   int mpi_size , mpi_rank , omp_rank , omp_size = 6;
   MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&mpi_rank);
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&mpi_size);
   omp_set_num_threads(omp_size);
   #pragma omp parallel default(none) private(omp_rank) shared(mpi_size,mpi_rank) firstprivate(test)
   {
   omp_rank = omp_get_thread_num();
   test[mpi_rank+mpi_size*omp_rank] = 1.;
   }
   MPI_Finalize();
   if( mpi_rank==0 ){printf("\ntest = ");
   for(int i=0 ; i<mpi_size*omp_size ; ++i ) printf("%.1f ", test[i]);}
   printf("\n");
   return(0);
}
```

However, the output is as follows:

```
test = 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Can anyone please help me understand why my code is not updating the array elements? When I try having each thread print the entire array after they update their specific element, it looks like each thread updates their specific element  correctly but resets every other element to 0.0. Thanks!

Comment: It is because `firstprivate(test)` clause will create a private (local) copy of array `test` for each thread. The OpenMP threads modify this private array not the one defined in `main`.  You should use `shared(test)` clause. Note that `mpi_rank+mpi_size*omp_rank` or `mpi_size*omp_size` may be bigger than the size of the array (6).

Comment: MPI uses distributed memory, so each process has its own array. The way you index the `test` array looks like you think it's shared. Try printing out the value of `mpi_rank+mpi_size*omp_rank` every time you do that assignment. And note that the array is only 6 places long.

Comment: Thanks, @Laci and @Victor! I was careful to use 2 MPI processes and 3 threads per process to match the array size. I tried changing scope of test from private to shared and printed out the index value mpi_rank+mpi_size*omp_rank. The index value seems fine and each thread corrects updates the value at that index. However, all other values are shown to be zero. In addition, my output looks like this now:

test = 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0

Comment: rank 0 populates `test[0:2]` and rank 1 populates `test[3:5]`. One option is to have each rank prints its portion (but output will be interleaved), or `MPI_Gather()` the (sub) arrays on rank 0 and print it from there. Since a given rank only touches 3 elements, you should declare `double local_test[3]` to reduce the memory footprint.